# Can only get one result Dom Crawler

Tags: symfony, dom, domcrawler

trying to get all the content within the h2 (to get the title of the article) in the div id=firehoselist but the following code only returns the first result.  Any ideas please

```
    $crawler = new Crawler($content);

    $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@id="firehoselist"]//*')->each(function (Crawler $node) use (&$results) {

        $results[] = trim($node->filter('h2')->text());

 });
```

content I'm trying to scrape is too messy to post here, but it is from the slashdot org website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//div[@id="firehoselist"]` is looking for **every** element which has the ID of `firehoselist` and will only get the **first** result of this entry `$node->filter('h2')->text()`.

What you need is to get **every** `#firehoselist h2` of the parsed html:

```
$crawler->filterXPath('//div[@id="firehoselist"]//h2')->each(function (Crawler $node) use (&$results) {

        $results[] = trim($node->text());

 });
```

Comment: Coolio thanks - also just needs an extra / to work like    $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@id="firehoselist"]//h2')->each(function (Crawler $node) use (&$results) {

Comment: just occured to me I actually wanted to get other elements in loop at the same time not just H2 - trying different combinations but can't work it out

Comment: I suppose `'//div[@id="firehoselist"]//*` will get you all the elements of the container with this id. Did you try it?

Comment: That does get the content, but now I can't figure how to get to the H2 value - why not  $node->filter('h2')->text(); returns error 'current node list is empty'

Comment: This error means you've got no `h2` element. Just print the insides to see what you've got.